# segmentation fault core dump after program runs and displays output

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have made some changes to my program that I started with: But for another reason I am getting a segmentation error. It happens after my output and I think it may have to do with my free statement in the destroy function. I ran it through gdb and it told me I was trying to access a 0X000000d memory location which is weird because I can print out the memory location of my struct and it shows something different. I know I have probably missed something very small. any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

had to take m code down since it is an on going project in school thanks for the replies I will post it back on once we have a grade.

Comment: Does you compiler not warn about using `UserOne` while it is uninitialized?

Comment: A small note unrelated to your problem: The [`assert` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) should not really be used to check for valid arguments or failure to allocate like that. First of all it might be disabled and do nothing depending on certain conditions, and secondly if the assertion fails then the program is aborted at that point which should never happen with any program used by a normal "user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *undefined behavior* in your code.

Take this line:

```
struct Person *UserOne=inputvalues(UserOne);
```

Here you define a variable `UserOne` and initialize it by calling the `inputvalues` function, for which you pass the *uninitialized* pointer. That means inside the `inputvalues` function, the `temp` pointer is uninitialized, and its value is *indeterminate* leading to said UB when you dereference the pointer.

One possible solution is to define a structure variable that is *not* a pointer, and use it when calling `inputvalues`, or by dynamically allocating a structure and pass to the function. Or to redesign the program to not pass an argument to the function at all, and let the function itself allocate the structure.

Using uninitialized variables like this is easily detectable by compilers, and most can issue warnings for it. If you don't get such a warning you might want to consider enabling more warnings.

Comment: @EOF There's no way of saying, really. UB is UB.